# Decomposing the normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

Does there exist a positive-only distribution such that the difference of two independent samples from this distribution is normally distributed? If so, does it have a simple form?

Comment: Interesting question! The normal distribution is infinitely decomposable, meaning you can always write it as the distribution of a sum $x_1+\ldots+x_n$ of an arbitrary number $n$ of random variables. But this is not the question.

Comment: If you get to the moment generating function, the question is whether or not $$e^{t\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2}=\varphi(t)\varphi(-t)$$ allows for a solution (in $\varphi$) that is a moment generating function of a positive variable...

Comment: You are correct, @Dilip: a difference of half-normals does not have a normal distribution.  The problem is not with the variance of the difference: the very shape of the distribution is not normal (its kurtosis is too great).

Comment: Although this is obvious, it may be worth noting that the statement is *approximately* correct.  After all, the difference of an $N(\mu,\sigma^2/2)$ variable and an $N(\mu,\sigma^2/2)$ variable has a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution and, by choosing $\mu$ sufficiently large, we can make the chance that either variable is negative as small as desired.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer to the question is No, and it follows
from a famous characterization of normal distributions.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.
Then so are $X$ and $-Y$ independent random variables,
and of course we can write $X-Y$ as $X + (-Y)$, the
sum of two independent random variables.
Now, according to a theorem conjectured by P. Lévy and 
proved by H. Cramér (see Feller, Chapter XV.8, Theorem 1),

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and
>   $X+Y$ is normally distributed, then both $X$ and $Y$ 
>   are normally distributed.

The OP asks whether there exist i.i.d. positive 
random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that 
$X-Y$ is normally distributed. But even if we dispense
with positivity and identical distributions, and keep
only the independence, normality of $X-Y = X + (-Y)$
requires that both $X$ and $-Y$ be normal random 
variables.  As Feller says, "the normal distribution
cannot be decomposed except in the trivial manner."

Comment: I was somewhat hoping the answer would be yes, but thanks! I don't have easy access to a copy of Feller - is it possible to sketch a proof of the theorem? It seems quite counterintuitive.

Comment: Even Feller does not include the original proof claiming that it is based on analytic function theory and thus quite different from his approach to characteristic functions.

Comment: I thought that was the case but it opens the door for dependent variables.  I was try to find a way to construct dependence between 2 positive half normals but couldn't quite get it to work.

Comment: well maybe someone should I was more interested in trying to solve it

Comment: I will make this a question and then you can spell out your answer.  I am not quite following what this joint density looks like and are you taking Z=|X|-|Y|?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I didn't have a clear picture as to what your example demonstrated.  I had said that I was attempting to construct a normal as the difference of two dependent half normals.  I was not sure it could be done but thought it was possible. I thought you were present an example of that.