# Can two dependent rvs X and Y that are nonnegative have a normal distribution for X-Y? Can it be done with half normals?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

A [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28787/decomposing-the-normal-distribution) was asked whether or not two independent variables $X$ and $Y$ that take on only positive values can have $X-Y$ be a normal distribution.  I was shown that the answer is no.  But I think that this can be done with two half normals that are dependent.  But I could not quite figure out how to structure the dependence.

Comment: Of course.  Just take $X = X^+ - X^-$. (They aren't half normal, but are nonnegative in the spirit of the title and the original question.)

Comment: I wasn't asking for half normal.  I just thought that it probably coul be done with half normals  In a comment in the discussion to the last problem Dilip suggested a solution to this question that involved two half normals.  I would like to see the details of that solution.

Comment: @cardinal I think if I understand your notation your example is too trivial and not what was intended by the question. A normal variable X is X+ when X is positive and -X- when X is negative by definition.

Comment: What do you mean "too trivial"? They are (dependent) identically distributed random variables such that the difference is a normal. It *exactly* answers the question. The construction has the benefit of drawing out exactly how and why one might expect it to be true. :)

Comment: @cardinal I was not saying that it was necessarily a bad answer.  But it is based on the definition that decomposes random variables into their positive and negative parts. It does of course fit the criterion of the question.  But if there is another solution involving half normals or any other pair of correlated random variables.

Comment: You will call this trivial as well, but any decomposition of the form $X=(X^++Y)-(X^-+Y)$ where $Y$ is a positive rv works. Including a half-normal rv.

Comment: The only reason Y needs to be a positive rv is that X+ + Y and X- + Y are both required to positive.  Yes adding and substrating the same variable is a trivial addition to cardinal's solution.  I would still like to see the half normal example.

Comment: Trivial as well: take two half-normal variables $Y$ and $Z$, then take $X=Y-(Y+Z)\delta$ where $\delta$ is $0$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$...

Comment: Here I think it is a little less trivial  because Y and Z can be indepedent and the dependence  is between Y and (Y+Z)δ .

Comment: Especially since $Y+Z$ is also half-normal.

Comment: @Xi'an Why is $Y+Z$ half-normal?  Is the sum of two half-normal random variables half normal? I very much doubt it.  $Y+Z$ is, of course, nonnegative as Michael wants.

Comment: I would still be interested in finding a way to do this with half normals.  But even though it looked to me like to would work I haven't found a way and since Dilip said his method did not involve half normals maybe it can't be done.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: yes indeed, my mistake!

Comment: Despite the "too trivial" remark, I find this to be an interesting question and upvoted it long ago. My comments and the extension provided by @Xi'an answer the first part. I have spent a little time thinking about the second part. There is one fairly obvious attack on this problem that could prove the second part to be false and also potentially prove an interesting property of the normal. I have not been able to resolve it either way at the present time.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Of course. Just take $X=X^+−X^−$. (They aren't half normal, but are nonnegative in the spirit of the title and the original question.) – cardinal

What do you mean "too trivial"? They are (dependent) identically distributed random variables such that the difference is a normal. It exactly answers the question. The construction has the benefit of drawing out exactly how and why one might expect it to be true. :) – cardinal

You will call this trivial as well, but any decomposition of the form $X=(X^++Y)−(X^−+Y)$ where $Y$ is a positive rv works. Including a half-normal rv. – Xi'an